# SQL Server 2008 R2 long hual remote clustering

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-clustering

I have a client that is asking if it is possiable to create a Active/Active cluster with 2 or more SQL Server 2008 R2 that are geographicly seperated.  For instance one server is in the Washington DC area and the other is in the LA area.

The basic need is to incress speed of access and content manipulation to an ASPX based webserver while keeping the data in sync.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible:

Check the following two links for additional information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189910.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/5f3e2199-4678-46aa-a34a-0439b79c96f5